# Prisma Query resolver fails: "invalid argument for the where selector"

Tags: graphql, prisma-graphql

I set up `prisma` with a `graphql yoga` server and have both GraphQL playgrounds available.

I could successfully create a conversation that I'm now trying to retrieve. I can't get this simple resolver to work in the Yoga GraphQL Playground:

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        conversation(parent: any, { id }: { id: string }, { prisma }: Context) {
            return prisma.conversation( { id } )
        }
    },
    Mutation: mutation
}
```

I used this query:

```
query getConversation {
  conversation(where: {
    id: "cjrqzinj4004e0a30ch4pccml"
  }) {
    id
    title    
  }
}
```

Error message is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "conversation": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "You provided an invalid argument for the where selector on Conversation.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "conversation"
      ],
      "code": 3040,
      "requestId": "local:cjrsahjoo00ai0a30a5y8mnvp"
    }
  ],
  "extensions": {}
}
```

The query works in the Prisma GraphQL playground.

Here is my data model:

```
type User {
  id: ID! @unique
  oauthId: String! @unique
  display: String!
  picture: String!
  likes: [Comment!]! @relation(name: "Likes")
  dislikes: [Comment!]! @relation(name: "Dislikes")
  bookmarks: [Comment!]! @relation(name: "Bookmarks")
  authorOf: [Comment!]! @relation(name: "Author")
  starterOf: [Conversation!]! @relation(name: "Starter")
}

type Attachment {
    id: ID! @unique
    name: String!
    createOn: DateTime!
    mediaType: String!
    comment: Comment! @relation(name: "Attachments")
}

type Comment {
    id: ID! @unique
    author: User! @relation(name: "Author")
    content: String!
    createDate: DateTime!
    parentConversation: Conversation @relation(name: "Conversation")
    parentComment: Comment @relation(name: "Replies")
    comments: [Comment!]! @relation(name: "Replies")
    bookmarkedBy: [User!]! @relation(name: "Bookmarks")
    likedBy: [User!]! @relation(name: "Likes")
    dislikedBy: [User!]! @relation(name: "Dislikes")
    attachments: [Attachment!]! @relation(name: "Attachments")
}

enum ParentType {
    Organization,
    Portfolio,
    Project,
    WbsComponent,
    WorkItem
}

type Parent {
    id: ID! @unique
    parent: String! @unique
    type: ParentType!
    conversations: [Conversation!]! @relation(name: "Parent")
}

type Conversation {
    id: ID! @unique
    parent: Parent! @relation(name: "Parent")
    organization: String!
    title: String!
    author: User! @relation(name: "Starter")
    createdOn: DateTime!
    comments: [Comment!]! @relation(name: "Conversation")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the Prisma forum. I was doing my destructuring wrong (note that `ConversationWhereUniqueInput` is a type provided by prisma):

```
export const conversation = (
    parent: any,
    { where: { id } }: { where: ConversationWhereUniqueInput },
    { prisma }: Context
): ConversationPromise => {
    return prisma.conversation({ id })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can try to pass `where` property to the `prisma` client

```js
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        conversation(parent: any, { id }: { id: string }, { prisma }: Context) {
            return prisma.conversation( { where: { id } )
        }
    },
    Mutation: mutation
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually posted this on Prisma forum, and got the answer: `export const conversation = (
 parent: any,
 { where: { id } }: { where: ConversationWhereUniqueInput },
 { prisma }: Context
): ConversationPromise => {
 return prisma.conversation({ id })
}
`